# Spark PipelineRDD toDF TypeError

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a udf that returns values that follow the format :

```
[
{u'description': None,
 u'location': None,
 u'list_field': [Row(details=None, name=u'John Smith', profile_url=None)],
 u'join_date': u'January 21st 2008',
 u'title': u'Potato Manager'},
 {u'description': Profile 2,
 u'location': None,
 u'list_field': [Row(details=None, name=u'Tony Montana', profile_url=None)],
 u'join_date': u'January 21st 2012',
 u'title': u'Awesomeness Specialist'}
]
```

As you can see, the return value has multiple types (it returns a list of dicts, on which some fields' values are another list of dicts). How would I go and create the udf? I have tried doing:

```
filter_udf = udf(func, ArrayType(MapType(StringType(),ArrayType(StringType(),StringType()))))
```

That is, specifying the most complex return node. But that is giving me errors.

Comment: For starters this is not a valid schema definition.

Comment: would you mind elaborate a bit?

Comment: First  of all you should replace `MapType(StringType,ArrayType(...` with `MapType(StringType(), ArrayType(...`.  Following is incorrect `ArrayType(StringType(),StringType())` although shouldn't complain (second argument for array should be boolean). Finally it won't match the records. There are probably some other issue here I've missed.

Comment: Python dictionaries are not the best choice here either.

Comment: yeah using StringType instead of StringType() was just a typo on the post.

Comment: What i have realized is that some of the nested fields are spark Rows, I think that is the issue.